# YouTube video tracking using dtm

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics, web-analytics

I am trying to implement youtube video tracking using DTM. I read few posts around capturing different events but couldnt got it working. 
I do have media module as part of appmeasurement library in DTM.

Does it need to be a custom script or we can capture values in dataelements?

Any pointers would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get it working with Adobe's Media module and youtube event 'onStateChange' tracking

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.adlytics.de/omniture/plugins/youtube-player-tracking.htm) out. There is some information you might find useful.